# Is it possible to enhance the CoordinatesTool by manipulating its associated package?

Tags: graphics, packages

Mathematica has a **Coordinates Tool** which is part of **tools&actions** which show up if one clicks on a Graphics or a picture. Coordinates Tool lets you digitize pixels from a graphics or picture in a notebook. Most probably it is part a package using Dynamics, since the tool is only accessible if Dynamics is permitted for the notebook.

**CAVE:** New digitized points are prepended to the already existing list! The resultant list is in the reversed order of marking!

There is an option called **Tooltip Options** which lets you adjust the magnification of the magnifying glass when digitizing. It may be for example the +-19 Pixels (called 39x39) around the crosshair or up to +-1 pixel (called 3x3. This one is not really useful and the next coarser one, +-4 (called 9x9) is ok.).

Already digitized points are shown as orange dots with a white hole in the middle.
Apparently the Coordinates Tool deletes an entry from the digitized list, when one clicks on it with the key **Ctl** depressed while the orange dot indicating the marked point has become a bit larger and the white hole in its middle has vanished such that it becomes a solid orange dot.
What exactly is the capturing range for this feature? Can one influence its size?
If the tool is part of a package which can be modified,

- I would like to add a counter of how many points have been digitized
  so far.
- I would like to sort the digitized points by clicking on a column of the list of digitized points. (To make that useful, however one should be able to exclude some fitting points from that sorting, e.g. a certain number of dots at the beginning of marking (i.e. at the end of the list) and I would like to display them e.g. on another background.
- I would like something to double-click on an entry in the list to show a crosshair across the whole graphics or image to highlight the associated marked point, which should be selected as well (i.e. without the white dot) and an other doubleclick to undo such an action. I want to be able to delete such a selected point with a keyboard action, e.g. pressing **Delete** or **Backspace**.

**Is my suspicion is right, that CoordinatesTool is part of a package of Mathematica, which I could modified myself?**
**Where which package and where is it located?**

Comment: The "Get coordinates" tool for graphics and the "Coordinates tool" for images are both implemented fully in the front-end as far as I know, so no way of modifying its behavior in any meaningful way. You can take a look at [`ResourceFunction["InteractiveGraphics"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InteractiveGraphics), which is my attempt at implementing something similar to the "Get coordinates" tool for graphics, but with slightly different behavior